# post data lost in transit from IE8 to IIS

Tags: iis, post, internet-explorer-8

I have a very strange problem with post data being lost in transit. The log-in form for our ASP web app has a  for submitting the username / password. The ASP page then receives this post, checks the credentials, and re-directs successful log ins. The problem I'm seeing is that intermittently the post data is just dropped. The request appears on the server, but there is no data. Client side is IE8, server side is IIS running ASP. The user will be fine for a time, and then as soon as they get his error, they have to restart the machine to solve it. What could be causing this and what type of diagnostics can I run to locate the problem?

Comment: http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: ASP. but I don't think the problem is server side.

Comment: You might want to check this out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) tool for inspecting client-server http communication. Maybe something is dropping data between client and server.

Comment: how do I set up fiddler to use a proxy itself?

Comment: Check http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp, "Can Fiddler "chain" to an upstream proxy?"

Comment: yea... we are using file:// style proxies... so apparently fiddler won't work.

Comment: You can simply copy your proxy script from the file share to a HTTP server and pull it down like that. Using File-delivered PAC files is generally risky because WinHTTP can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

You can save each request which you receive in server in some file and to see if they really does not send you nothing. Try to see IIS log for error. Maybe your IIS is busy with other requests and refuse to accept this one. Than it will send 500 error to the client.